# Detect subproperty change in PropertyChangedCallback and get the subproperty

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, dependencyobject

I am using `DepdendencyObject`s with `PropertyChangedCallback`s and I want to detect a subproperty-change inside of this callback. The proplem is that the `DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs`-Object does only let me see the Property that contains the `DP` containing the Property that changed. Is there any way to reach this Subproperty?

```
class MainClass : DepencencyObject
{
    public ComplexObject MainProperty
    {
        get { return (ComplexObject)GetValue(MainPropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MainPropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MainPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MainProperty", 
        typeof(ComplexObject), typeof(MainClass), 
        new PropertyMetadata(new ComplexObject([...])));

    private static void MainProperty_PropertyChangedCallback(... DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Unable to detect a change, if 'ComplexObject.SubProperty'
        // changes; it is shown like a change of 'MainProperty'
    }
}

class ComplexObject : DepencencyObject
{
    public int SubProperty
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(SubPropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SubPropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SubPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SubProperty", 
        typeof(int), typeof(ComplexObject), 
        new PropertyMetadata(0));
}
```

Someone does

```
(new MainClass()).MainProperty.SubProperty = 100000;
```

and the PropertyChangedCallback is called because `MainProperty`changed (not `SubProperty`).

Comment: You need a bit more code so we can help out

Comment: I have added some code

Comment: Your binding will correctly listen to the sub property. I'm going to guess your not using bindings to listen for this change?

Comment: It does not matter where the value comes from.

Comment: You need to subscribe to the changes on the subproperty in the MainProperty and bubble that up to the caller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deriving your `ComplexObject`, from `Freezable` (and implementing `Freezable`) should be enough, or not?

According to MSDN Documentation:

*A class that derives from Freezable gains the following features:*

- *Special states: a read-only (frozen) state and a writable state.*
- *Thread safety: a frozen Freezable object can be shared across threads.*
- **Detailed change notification: Unlike other DependencyObject objects, a Freezable object provides change notifications when sub-property values change.**
- *Easy cloning: the Freezable class has already implemented several methods that produce deep clones.*